# sencha2.2.0 + phonegap - error in build-impl.xml - delete doesn't support the "todir" attribute

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want integrate phonegap2.7.0 with sencha touch2.2.0. 
I change build-impl.xml file to copy files to www.

```
<target name="-after-build">
        <delete todir="../../android/assets/www"/>
        <copy todir="../../android/assets/www">
            <fileset dir="${workspace.build.dir}/package"/>
        </copy>

    </target>
```

During build I get an error:

```
[INF]
[INF] run:
[INF]
[INF] -build:
[INF]
[INF] -after-build:
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: delete doesn'''t support the "todir" attribute

[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 55 seconds
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: delete doesn't support the "todir" attribute
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Sencha's build is based on `Ant` so I suppose delete also follows same convention which says use `dir` which is **The directory to delete, including all its files and subdirectories.** as per [docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html). Moreover, logically also **to** and **from** doesn't make sense in delete operation so this should work:

```
<target name="-after-build">
    <delete dir="../../android/assets/www"/>
    <copy todir="../../android/assets/www">
        <fileset dir="${workspace.build.dir}/package"/>
    </copy>
</target>
```